# How to find an element by its tag and it is located in multiple div in Selenium using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to find a specific element in my page and then click on it, this element doesn't have a specific unique ID or any other, and its index is not fixed it may be changed, thus how can I find this element in the simplest way "I'm just trying and learning selenium and still in the beginning"
as in the attached image, the uniqueness is in the tag "p" (Processes Portfolio)

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Comment: Screenshots of the UI are great, screenshots of code or HTML are not. Please read why [a screenshot of code/HTML is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code/HTML as text and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this XPATH expression:

```
//p[text()='Processes Portfolio']
```

**Explanation:** This relative XPATH expression will search the entire DOM for text "Processes Portfolio" within the tags `<p>`